# Will solid state EV batteries be chargeable using current chargers?

Tags: battery, charging, electric-vehicle, theory

It seems that solid state batteries in EVs may be only a few years off. Does anyone know whether current charging systems/plugs will be capable of charging these batteries?

Comment: Afaik all current EV charging systems just provide power to the car for charging. The actual battery management/charge controller is built into the car itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not read anything which would lead me to believe the charging systems available today will not be used to charge solid state batteries. For the most part, power delivery for *any battery* is exactly the same. The differences lie in how the battery itself receives the power, which is done on the vehicle side, not the delivery side. The vehicle decides how much power the battery should take in what amounts so as not to cause damage (or produce the least amount of damage) to the battery. The charger just supplies the juice. Whether the battery is Solid State or wet, all they do is retain the energy.

As far as the charging ports/plugs, with both [Ford and GM announcing they'll be going to the Tesla NACS ports by 2025](https://www.motortrend.com/news/general-motors-tesla-nacs-ev-charging-port/), I would bet other manufacturers will be following suit. Ultimately it seems the Tesla charging station design will likely become the recharge delivery model going forward to help standardize the industry, at least here in North America.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, Tesla & Ford are going to share those resources in the UK too, so there's hope for it being worldwide, not just a single territory.